# JavaScript: Creating web app to run offline and optionally on mobile device as well

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I am looking into various frameworks and flatfile/nosql systems to be able to create an application that runs offline with:

- Offline/flat file database (couchdb, mongodb, etc)
- Some javascript framework (backbone, angularjs, knockout, etc)
- Optionally works on mobile if we use bootstrap 3 (whose main focus is mobile first)

And avoid server-side languages such as php, etc or database systems like mysql or sqlite.

Let's say I create a simple todo application with these:

- [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) (javascript as language of choice for the app)
- [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) (portable db system, no need for mysql or sqlite, etc)
- [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) (so layout and app works on mobile devices as well)

My question is if we use above three, will my todo app work completely offline (and optionally on mobile devices) since everything related to the app will be within its folder including database. am I missing something ? In other words, I should be able to run the app by moving app folder to any location or even on different pc without any external dependencies (like mysql or server-side language) ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that MongoDB is not designed to be embedded as such :

> portable db system, no need for mysql or sqlite, etc

I must contradict what you say there, SQLite would actually be a better fit if you wish to use the application offline with full database capabilities.

You can, of course, with various JavaScript frameworks take advantage of HTML5 storage which can then synchronise with your sever-side MongoDB instance.

In fact if you did this right you can create a IE/Firefox/Chrome application and actually have no app folder at all and then have a single roaming profile for that user stored within the browser. Basically you could make this quite interesting by utilising the latest technologies.

Comment: +1 thanks for the insight. Is there any other portable database that we could put in app's folder other than sqlite similar to mangodb or some other flat file portable db system ? I would want go with localStorage but it is very limited and there is no point of sync with mangodb since I am expecting to run app completely offline. Any idea ?

Comment: @Dev01 not off the top of my head, I don't have too much experience in embedded databases but I know that most games like fallout, skyrim, etc all use SQLite.

Comment: You should also checkout firebase.

Answer (score -1):

In ancient times, I used to use xmls to work offline base, but there were version issues. Now you can do it with json db as offline. And you should  be aware that there is lot of sync issues to compromise, while using two or more ver of db. Cu